# How to populate the get data in the edit modal?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, svelte

In my Svelte app, I have the API get request function in the App.svelte file

```
let events = []
export function getEvents(){
fetch([url])
.then(response => response.json())
.then(result => events = result)
.catch(err => console.log('Request Failed', err))
}
onMount(() => {
getEvents()
})
```

then I listed the events array like this

```
{#each events.filter(event => event.status.includes('upcoming')) as event (event.eventId)}
<div class="event-card">
<h2>{event.eventName}</h2>
<h2>{new Date(event.timeFrom * 1000).toLocaleString()} - {new Date(event.timeTo * 1000).toLocaleString()}</h2>
<p>{event.status} </p>
<button on:click={editEvent}>edit</button>
<button id="delete" on:click={() => deleteEvent(event.eventId)}>delete</button>
</div>
{/each}
```

I got the deletion function working when it was time for editing however, I had trouble populating the data from events to show in a modal to be edited. the Modal is a separate component in a different Svelte file imported by App.svelte. Should I put the modal inside App.Svelte instead? or is there a better way to do this?
the goal here is that when an edit button is pressed, it gets its 'eventId' and when the form is submitted (in a modal or anything else), it would trigger a put request to the API (I already wrote this function, and tested it and it's working). So how can I make it know which event the user is editing?